# Como selecionar registros separados em varias páginas de uma paginação em PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, paginação

Como selecionar todos os registros de uma paginação? Semelhante ao que o gmail faz onde sempre , ao marcar o `checkbox` que seleciona somente a da página atual, aparece logo acima um texto para selecionar todos os outros registros que estão separados em várias páginas da paginação. Isso em PHP.

Exemplo no gmail mesmo depois de uma pesquisa, a pagina mostra 100 resultados, mais é possivel selecionar tb todos os registros somente referentes aquela pesquisa que estão nas outras paginas da paginação.

Comment: Pergunta muito ampla. Mostre o código de como está fazendo a sua paginação atualmente para que possamos ter uma base. Edite sua pergunta e acrescente algum código.

Answer (score 1):

Eu faria da seguinte forma:

(1) Posicione uma checkbox em um local destacado na página (indicando que trata-se de uma seleção múltipla);

(2) Faça com que o clique na checkbox ative um javascript onde:

(a) todos os elementos checkbox visíveis da página sejam selecionados (para dar o efeito de seleção total);
   (b) realize uma seleção de todos os elementos do critério (independente de estarem listados ou não na página). Nas minhas aplicações, gosto de mostrar ao lado do seletor o número total de itens selecionados, isso dá uma confirmação adicional ao usuário que ele selecionou todos os itens e não apenas os da página.

(3) Realize a sua operação.

O que o GMAIL faz é idêntico ao acima. Ao realizarmos um filtro ele faz o seguinte procedimento 1º executa a query e guarda o resultado, 2º mostra um número x de resultados, 3º ao selecionar todas ele marca os x resultados na tela (apenas para efeitos de apresentação) e 4º executa a ação sobre todo o resultado da query guardado no 1º passo.

Boa sorte!

Comment: obrigado amigo, é isso mesmo que preciso, vc teria algum exemplo de codigo do 4º ??

Answer (score 0):

A princípio, tudo o que é necessário é uma variável *booleana*. Exemplo:

```
// no client-side (javascript)
var todos_registros = false;   // valor inicial

// no server-side (php)
todos_registros = boolval($_REQUEST['todos_registros']);   // recebendo via Ajax
```

Use Ajax para sincronizar o valor da variável, enviando/recebendo o seu valor entre cliente e servidor.

Aí o que você faz com essa variável? No *client-side*, apenas marque todos os *checkboxes* ou equivalente como `checked`. Ou atualize a interface de algum outro modo que o usuário saiba que selecionou tudo. (Em suma: cuide da UX.)

No *server-side* você verifica: se `todos_registros` for `true` então você realiza a operação em todos os registros.

Answer (score 0):

Suponhamos que você tenha, em client-side, uma série de registros, cada um associado a um checkbox:

```
<ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="messages[]" value="message1">Mensagem 1</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="messages[]" value="message2">Mensagem 2</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="messages[]" value="message3">Mensagem 3</li>
</ul>
```

Repare que cada checkbox tem como nome uma referência ao array `messages`. Assim, quando você submeter esse form, esse será o array de resultados que você terá em server side:

```
Array
(
    [messages] => Array
        (
            [0] => message1
            [1] => message2
            [2] => message3
        )
)
```

Espero que resolva o que você tem em mente – pessoalmente, acho a solução mais pŕática.